# How can $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}E_i\in\mathscr{R}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, measure-theory

**Theorem**: Suppose $\mu:\mathscr{R}\to\mathbb{R}^+$ is non-negative and additive on a ring $\mathscr{R}$. Then

**(i)** if $E\in\mathscr{R}$, and $\{E_i\}$ is a sequence of disjoint sets of $\mathscr{R}$ such that $E\supset\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}E_i$

$\mu(E)\geqslant\sum_\limits{i=1}^{\infty}\mu(E_i)$;

**(ii)** if $E\in\mathscr{R}$, and $\{E_i\}$ is a sequence of disjoint sets of $\mathscr{R}$ such that $E\subset\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}E_i$

$\mu(E)\leqslant\sum_\limits{i=1}^{\infty}\mu(E_i)$;

**Question**:

On this theorem it is stated that $E\in\mathscr{R}$, and $E=\bigcup_\limits{i=1}^{\infty}$. However by the definition the ring is only closed for finite unions not for infinite unions. How can $E=\bigcup_\limits{i=1}^{\infty}\in\mathscr{R}$?

Is the author implying the Monotone class generated by the ring?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is it stated that $E=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}E_i$? I only encounter $\subset$ and $\supset$ in two distinct questions.

Comment: @drhab               But if you consider $E\supset \bigcup_\limits{i=1}^{\infty}E_i$. Then $E$ must be the union of infinite sets.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. *Every* set can be written as a union of infinite sets, so that says nothing. Even the empty set: $\varnothing=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ where $A_n=\varnothing$ for each $n$.

Comment: For example, if $\mathscr{R} \subseteq P(\mathbb{R})$ is the ring of finite unions of intervals, then $(0, 1) \supset \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{2i+1}, \frac{1}{2i})$.